# What are the weird characters from an image file?

Tags: linux, cat, images, nano

So i am pretty new to linux and i am learning basic commands. I am also very interested to know how things work under the hood, so sometime after i learned both the cat and nano commands, i tried using them on an image, and all these weird symbols appeared (linux mint):

[image: the image (index.jpeg) as a file after using nano on it]

I also tried it on kali, i got the same thing, so i believe it has to do with how images are stored at a bit level, but again i am at the beginning and i couldn't find any explication to what exactly these symbols mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All files are made of 1s and 0s, each of which is called a bit. A "byte" is 8 bits. For 8 bits, there are 256 possible combinations of 1s and 0s.

The data in plain text files, which is what `nano` is meant to edit (and terminals expect to output with `cat`) is divided into bytes. Typically, each character in the file makes up one byte. In ASCII encoding, for example, the letter "A" is the byte 01000001. Some character encodings like UTF-8 sometimes use multiple bytes to represent a character, since there are more than 256 characters they need to cover, but they still divide the file into bytes. (There are also bytes for "Control characters" like "Control-J" for a linebreak.)

Images are binary files, not text files; their bits can be divided into bytes as well, but these bytes are not meant to represent characters/letters.

What's happening when a non-text file is opened as a text file is that the text editor tries to interpret the bytes of the binary file as if they were meant to represent characters. Since they weren't meant to do that, there's a pretty much random correlation between the bytes of the binary file and the characters those same bytes would represent if the file actually were a text file. However, that's what nano is trying to interpret the file as, so you get random characters, many of which are control characters which aren't typically meant to be printed and so produce strange results.

That's the way I understand what's going on anyway. I'm not a computer scientist by any stretch of the imagination, so I hope commenters will improve upon my answer if need be.

Obviously, if you want to edit an image you should use an image editor like gimp or krita instead, not a text editor. You could I suppose use a binary editor or hex editor, etc., but that would require very detailed knowledge about how the image format turns the data it represents into bits and bytes, which I believe is different for different image formats.

Comment: thank you very much, i now understand why all those symbols are there